# JustCode broke my Error list

Tags: visual-studio-2010, justcode

lately I remove just code from my machine and since than my error list is broken.
This code (in the real time error detection) is legit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            fifi.ff.ww;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you mean intellisense is not warning you about errors? Can you try opening Visual Studio in safe mode and check if it works? devenv /SafeMode

Comment: @Ganesh R yes, the intellisense dont work properly, also it's don't work in safe mode

Comment: The best thing I can suggest is repair Visual Studio (reinstall SP1 if applied after repair)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bring back the Visual Studio error reporting from `Visual Studio Tools - Options - Text Editor - C# - Advanced - Underline errors in the editor/Show live semantic errors`

JustCode has built-in error reporting and it stops the Visual Studio one as the editor gets quite messy with both of them.